# Which sentence sounds natural?

Tags: grammaticality

Which sentence is grammatically correct? Which one sounds the most natural to you?

*1. He spent his formative years in one country, and I in another.*

*2. He spent his formative years in one country, and me in another.*

*3. He spent his formative years in a different country than me.*

*4. He spent his formative years in a different country than I.*

I'm confused because Grammarly shows them all as being correct, but some seem outright wrong to me.

Comment: Which seem wrong? Why do they seem wrong? What specific part of this is confusing you? Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: #4 with "did" added to the end sounds most natural to me.

Comment: Why not: "We spent our formative years in different countries."

Comment: I like 1 and would rate 2 as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

I will use 1 or 4, nominative case, always, and I like 1 better.  I don't make it a point to correct others, only speak and write it that way.  But since it is asked...

different from me is common usage, but I'm in the camp that looks at this as "in a different country than I spent my formative years"; therefore, I will use different from I.  It may sound stilted, because different from is usually followed by the objective case (he is different from me), but here there is an omitted relative clause where I, the subject of that clause, is the only word present.

He spent...and I (spent my formative years) in another.  This is parallel structure.  If I think I am going to sound stilted, I state the full relative pronoun clause:  "in a different country where I spent my formative years."  That still comes across as long-winded.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use 3 or 4, they just seem a bit clunky and confusing, the first 2 sound the most natural in my opinion if you are trying to do a first person narrative, choose between them depending on the personality/style of the character.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the first one sounds a tad more formal than the second one-- as proposed by user7266757, in a textual/explanative context I would use the first one say I was conversing amongst those older than me- but I would say that if I didn't need to sound so formal and upheld- I would definitely use the second one as it adds a bit more personality wherein I'm using a smoother word (smoother to me of course, and dependent on how you say it, really.).

The third and fourth statements sort of propose that there is perhaps a concern or need to explicitly address the fact that 'he' is in another country- this is derived from the word 'than' which would declare a comparison of two clauses.
Similar to when you say:

- *"He had had more than he could handle."*
- *"She thought that England was better than Spain"*

You're comparing two things together, in the first case; it shows that the person was giving distaste to being over-encumbered with something, it's a hard thing to explain really. In my words I would somehow say that the first and third negate each other in the way that the third one shows more emphasis on one clause, but the first one neutralizes that feeling and puts no sort of emphasis over the entire statement.